# How can I call a function in a class from a collider method when this is a different scope?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm using WebPack to build my game and I've run into a scoping issue. I'll try and explain.

My TestScene class file:

```
import 'phaser';
import Npcs from 'modules/Npcs.js';

const npcs = new Npcs()

export class TestScene extends Phaser.Scene {

  constructor () {
    super('TestScene')
  }

  preload(){...}

  create(){
    this.physics.add.collider(
      this.player,
      this.bombs,
      npcs.hitBomb,
      null,
      this
    )
  }

}
```

My Npcs class file:

```
import 'phaser';

const gameplayStates = new GameplayStates()

export default class Npcs {

  hitBomb (player, bomb) {
    this.physics.pause();
    player.setTint(0xff0000);
    this.entityDestroy()
  }

  entityDestroy () {
  console.log('destroyed')
  }

}
```

`this.player` and `this.bombs` are in place and work as expected in every way I intended.

The callback in the collider method has `this`(testScene) as the context so, `this.entityDestroy()` no longer seems to work and fires the error:
 `app.bundle.js:116068 Uncaught TypeError: this.entityDestroy is not a function`.

I suspect this is because the `npcs` class is not the scope of `this` when the method is called from the collider.

What is the correct way to get around this with the collider method?

Thanks all,

Your help is much appreciated.
MHC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've asked around the www and got a satisfying solution to my issue.

The main solution I've gotten most is to change the context in the collider method. Like so:

```
this.physics.add.collider(
  this.player,
  this.bombs,
  npcs.hitBomb,
  null,
  npcs
)
```

Where the npcs class becomes the context for the hitBomb function. The issue with that solution is that I can no longer reference `this`(the scene reference) in the npcs function any longer. 
The best work around I've found, which adds more lines of code, is:

```
this.physics.add.collider(
  this.player,
  this.bombs,
  function (player, bomb) {
    this.physics.pause();
    npcs.hitBomb(player, bomb);
  },
  null,
  this
)
```

This has more lines of code but it allows me to keep the scope of the scene I'm calling the collider function from and establish the scope of npcs class.

Thanks to everyone who took the time to chat with me and help me find a solution.